# How to set the path in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

Help when I do 'ffmpeg', I get

`ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

However, when I do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib ffmpeg`, I get

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 11 2012 18:52:29 with gcc 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-shared --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-nonfree --enable-libtheora --enable-version3
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Can someone tell me how to set this permanently. I am a newbie to the linux command window. I saw something about editing the /etc/ld.so.conf file, but I don't know how to do that exactly. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `/usr/local/lib ffmpeg`? Did you mean `/usr/local/lib/ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit one of these files:

1. /etc/profile
2. ~/.bash_profile
3. ~/.bash_login
4. ~/.profile

And add: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib ffmpeg

Then reboot

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file (depending on the shell you're using). That way it'll get set for each shell process you open.

This modification will be particular to you. Editing the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file is a system-wide modification.

Comment: Thank you, Brian, but I don't know where to look for the .profile or .bashrc file(s). Still sooooo new to linux.

Comment: Thanks for the differentiation between sitewide settings and user-particular settings